# SQLite or PouchDB+SQLite. Professional advice needed

Tags: sqlite, pouchdb

I am developing a vocabulary + quizzes app. For every word, I need to store an image and multiple audio files. I need some professional advice on:

1.Use SQLite directly or PouchDB with SQLite adapter. The app is completely offline. No DB sync.

2.Save image and audio files directly as binaries into the DB or save names only into the DB and the actual files to the local file system. I know it’s never been a good idea saving binaries into DB. PouchDB has sort of “attachments”. If the answer to my question 1 is PouchDB, should I use it to save binaries or not?

Thx.

Comment: You've only mentioned databases. What platform are you using to create the app in? Is it a native java app? A web app? A phonegap/cordova app?

Comment: thx for your help Mike. it's an Ionic 3 App.

Comment: I would store binaries as files and then just use whatever is easiest for you as a database. If you like SQL, use SQLite. I like PouchDB and NOSQL - but you don't have significant data requirements (or sync), so just use whatever data store seems easiest for you to use.